# library that convert xml or Json to html file

Tags: java, html, xml

I need a library that convert xml or Json to html file with default design for tags. If I need to change the html file later to change specific thing in the design I can access the html file.

To explain more what I really want is an HTML template, for example:

> http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm

try to add the JSON code below:

```
{
    "balancepage": {
        "title": "Hello",
        "balances": {
            "balance": [
                {
                    "country": "leb",
                    "curency": "lbp",
                    "_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "country": "leb",
                    "currency": "us",
                    "default": "true",
                    "_id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "country": "leb",
                    "curency": "lbp",
                    "_id": "3"
                }
            ],
            "default": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Than when I press render It will show tables representing a default form for the JSON code that I didn't write.

what similar libraries that I can use, I give it a JSON file and it returns an HTML file that I can show it to the user.

Comment: not aware any lib for JSON, but for XML to HTML, you may consider look into XSLT lib such as Xalan-J https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/